# Video.js and Videojs-record - requirement to press buttons to start recording

Tags: javascript, video.js, recording, video-recording, videojs-record

I've inherited a project that uses [video.js](https://videojs.com/getting-started/#download-npm) and [videojs-record](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record)

In the project I've inherited, the user of the app is required to click twice before recording starts - first, on the camera icon in the middle of the player, and second on the circle 'record' button on the bottom left. (There's also a requirement to accept permissions the first time, but I'm not personally worried about that requirement as I understand its necessity).

But realistically, for my use case, I don't want to ask the user to click anything to record. I want to start recording programatically through javascript, once permissions are accepted.

[But even all the examples](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record#examples) have the user required to click those two buttons, so I'm starting to think there's no way around it. I looked through all the [options](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record#options) and I couldn't find any for this. I see the functions `start` and `stop` but when i do `player.start()` and `player.stop()` it says undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start the device use player.record().start()

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="video-js">
    <button (click)="startRecording()" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
    <button (click)="stopRecording()" class="btn btn-warn">Stop</button>

    <video id="video_{{idx}}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"></video>
</div>
```

Sharing Screen & Starting the recorder:

```
startRecording(){
        this.player.record().getDevice();
    }
```

Stopping the recorder:

```
stopRecording(){
        this.player.record().stop();
    }
```

AfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      ....

      // device is ready
      this.player.on('deviceReady', () => {
        console.log('device is ready!');
        this.player.record().start(); // <-- IMPORTANT*
      });
  
      // user clicked the record button and started recording
      this.player.on('startRecord', () => {
        console.log('started recording!');
      });
  
      // user completed recording and stream is available
      this.player.on('finishRecord', () => {
        // show save as dialog
        console.log('finished recording: ', this.player.recordedData);
        this.player.record().saveAs({'video': 'my-video-file-name.webm'});
    });
  
      ....
    }
```

I have specified a line as `IMPORTANT*`, this line is important for starting the recorder, as otherwise it would only initiate screen-sharing.

Answer (score 0):

your HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="startRecord()">Start</button>
<button (click)="camOn()" class="btn btn-primary">i am ready</button>
<button (click)="stopRecording()" class="btn btn-warn">Stop</button>
```

TS/JS

```
startRecord() {
this.player.record().start();
}
camOn() {
this.player.record().getDevice();
}
stopRecording() {
this.player.record().stop();
}
```